Damaged Shower Floor- Is it just a matter of replacing the tile or more?
I just bought a new home. It came to our attention that some of the glass tiles have come loose in the shower. Some of them you can see underneath, which is a little worrisome. Not sure if that means water has gotten underneath.
My question is, can we just regrout and replace the tiles? Or do I have to put in a new pan and everything? I’m worried about waterproofing because of the way that those tiles look. But at the same time I don’t see any signs of water damage otherwise which would make me think that the shower pan is may be fine. And I’m not even sure if that’s why those tiles look that way or just the adhesive underneath has come loose.
Estimates of redoing everything without doing it myself are a little under 6k, so I prefer to DIY if possible.
Has anyone seen tile that looks like this where the texture has changed on some and you can see the backing? When I google I didn’t really see anything that looks similar.
Thank you!


The loose tiles might be just because the mastic/glue was a bit thinner under them and did not stick down well, or the pan is not ridged enough and movement pop them.  First one is just cleaning the base and redoing the tiles(easy).  The second is harder and might be a total redo.

Thank you! That makes sense.

It's apparent there is not much thinset on those tiles. The best idea is remove all the tiles and retile. I see no need to tear up the entire base and pan.
It's tedious, (Or may be not with such little thinset.) Just pull the tiles and retile the floor.

That’s good to hear! Thank you!
It also looks like it’s not graded properly. I’m wondering if it was done wrong to begin with, or the house has settled.
